# Sliding Drawer Text

Tags: android

I would like the "Top Text" to move with the slider handle similar to how the "Bottom Text" does and be pushed off screen when the slider reaches the top.  Is this possible?  I don't necessarily need to use the SlidingDrawer, I just need the behavior is provides.  It would be nice if the answer was xml only.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
                android:layout_width="fill_parent"
                android:layout_height="fill_parent" >
    <TextView android:id="@+id/textViewTop"
              android:layout_width="wrap_content"
              android:layout_height="wrap_content"
              android:text="Top Text" />
    <SlidingDrawer android:id="@+id/SlidingDrawer"
                   android:layout_width="fill_parent"
                   android:layout_height="fill_parent"
                   android:content="@+id/contentLayout"
                   android:handle="@+id/slideHandleButton" >
    <Button android:id="@+id/slideHandleButton"
            android:layout_width="fill_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_gravity="center"
            android:text="Slider" >
    </Button>
    <LinearLayout android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                  android:id="@+id/contentLayout"
                  android:layout_height="wrap_content">
        <TextView android:id="@+id/textViewBottom"
                  android:text="Bottom Text"
                  android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                  android:layout_height="wrap_content" />
    </LinearLayout>
  </SlidingDrawer>
</RelativeLayout>
```

Comment: Move the TextView element so it is contained within `<SlidingDrawer> ... </SlidingDrawer>`. It currently isnt.

Comment: Where would I put that TextView so it appears above the handle?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`TextView` holding `Top Text` should be a part of SlidingDrawer. Currently it is not. Also, you have identical `ids` defined for top text and bottom text. I have changed that. See if the following fixes the issue:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
                android:layout_width="fill_parent"
                android:layout_height="fill_parent" >

    <SlidingDrawer android:id="@+id/SlidingDrawer"
                   android:layout_width="fill_parent"
                   android:layout_height="fill_parent"
                   android:content="@+id/contentLayout"
                   android:handle="@+id/contentLayoutTop" >

        <LinearLayout android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                  android:id="@+id/contentLayoutTop"
                  android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                  android:orientation="vertical" >

            <TextView android:id="@+id/textViewInTransitTop"
                  android:text="Top Text"
                  android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                  android:layout_height="wrap_content" />

            <Button android:id="@+id/slideHandleButton"
                android:layout_width="fill_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_gravity="center"
                android:text="Slider" >
            </Button>

        </LinearLayout>            

        <LinearLayout android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                  android:id="@+id/contentLayout"
                  android:layout_height="wrap_content">

            <TextView android:id="@+id/textViewInTransit"
                  android:text="Bottom Text"
                  android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                  android:layout_height="wrap_content" />

        </LinearLayout>

  </SlidingDrawer>

</RelativeLayout>
```

If you need the top text before (or after) `@+id/slideHandleButton`, change the order in which they are defined. If you need the button in line with the text, move the button declaration inside that LinearLayout that holds top text.

**Edit:**

> It would be nice if the answer was xml only.

I tried staying within your requirements, but this cannot be done in xml alone. Fortunately, the code part is straightforward:

In your activity's `onCreate(Bundle)`:

```
SlidingDrawer slidingDrawer = (SlidingDrawer) findViewById(R.id.SlidingDrawer);

final TextView textViewInTransitTop = (TextView)
                                findViewById(R.id.textViewInTransitTop);

slidingDrawer.setOnDrawerOpenListener(new OnDrawerOpenListener() {

    @Override
    public void onDrawerOpened() {

        // Drawer's been opened // Don't use View.INVISIBLE
        textViewInTransitTop.setVisibility(View.GONE);              
    }
});

slidingDrawer.setOnDrawerCloseListener(new OnDrawerCloseListener() {

    @Override
    public void onDrawerClosed() {

        // Text on top is back again
        textViewInTransitTop.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);               
    }
});
```

Comment: Bottom Text does not appear anyone on the screen

Comment: @Robert Sorry, made a mistake in xml. Try now.

Comment: @Robert Give it another try.

Comment: Very close, the only thing it's not doing is pushing the "Top Text" off screen when it reaches the top.

Comment: @Robert See the edit above. It requires a few lines of code as I couldn't find an xml-only solution.

Comment: The Top Text needs to move with the slider.

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/37135/discussion-between-user2558882-and-robert)

Comment: @Robert [let us continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/37135/discussion-between-user2558882-and-robert)